# What does "me bateaste" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Someone used this term in an office while talking to a co-worker, about the project.

I have tried some research and Google suggests that it means literally *"You hit me"* or maybe *"You stood me up"*.

It is also some sort of a baseball reference; although I don't know very much about baseball so don't understand.

What is the accurate translation?
What is an equivalent expression used in England?
In what situation might someone use this?
What does it have to do with baseball?

Comment: It might help if you gave more context so we can see if it is indeed from baseball or more colloquial. I suspect the latter.

Comment: @mdewey  Edited.  They were talking about office work, not baseball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el norte de México (Monterrey) el hecho de batear a alguien implica el regresarle una acción que había sido inicialmente asignada o "tirada" hacia él.

Por ejemplo, si la persona A recomienda al jefe que persona B debe realizar cierto trabajo, sin embargo la persona B lo convence de que la persona A es la apropiada para hacerlo. En este caso, la persona B ha "bateado" a la persona A, al regresarle el trabajo que originalmente había sido "lanzado" hacia él.

Comment: I think this example best describes the situation I saw.

Answer (score 2):

'Batear', significa dejar o hacer de lado. 
Por ejemplo: 
 -Te declare mi amistad y me bateaste.
 -La junta bateo mi propuesta de este mes.

Answer (score 2):

*Batear* is to hit the ball in baseball but in some countries where Spanish is spoken it has other meanings, as you can see at the [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=batear).

In the context of work and with the grammatical form *"me bateaste"* I think it can mean: *you fired me*, *you deceived me*, *you beat me at an argument* or something similar.

Do you know what country those people are native from?

I will copy only the meanings used in Mexico:

> **I.  1.**    tr. *Mx.* Rechazar *una persona a alguien, principalmente en
>   requerimientos amorosos o sexuales.* pop + cult → espon.

In English: Of a person, to reject someone particularly in a romantic or sexual context.

> **2.**  *Mx.* Contestar *alguien* evasivamente preguntas comprometidas eludiendo aclarar lo que en ellas se demanda. pop + cult → espon.

In English: to prevaricate, to answer evasively.

> **II. 1.**    tr. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, Cu, RD, PR, Ve. En el juego de
>   pelota,* dar con el **bate** a la pelota.

In English: to hit the ball with the bat in a ball game.

> **III. 1.**    tr. *Mx, ES.* Echar *una
>   persona* a *alguien* de su cargo o puesto de trabajo. pop.

In English: Of a person, to fire someone from his role or job.

Comment: If you visit the link in my answer you can see some meanings used in Mexico, them are labeled with  _Mx._ abreviation. My English isn't so good for translate all of them but you can use a online translator to get an idea

Comment: If you fancy copying them into your post and having a go at translation I will edit it for you. Two of the three I think I can understand but the first one defeated me.

Comment: The first one I think can translate as _a person reject someone who is in love with him/her_